# How to load data from JSON files into MySQL instance with the Django ORM?

Tags: python, mysql, json, django, orm

I'm using Django to build out an ETL engine and I've built out some methods to extract and transform data from some API endpoints that is being saved locally to my machine in .JSON format. File formats nomenclature is as follows: `repos_transformed_2019-05-06-13-23-59.json` and `repos_extraction_2019-05-06-13-23-59.json` in case that matters for the Django ORM's lookup.

I've got a MySQL instance running that has schema that matches up exactly with the keys that are defined in my .JSON file but the Django ORM is not loading the data into my database from the `loaddata` command. I have to manually create an instance of the model and hardcode it all in manually. Obviously this would not work in a production environment and I'm trying to find a way to load this data in in .json file "batches" without having to manually crank away at this.

After reading the docs (specifically `loaddata`) I am trying to load it into my database like so:

`django-admin loaddata repos_transformed_2019-05-06-13-23-59.json --database invisible-hand`

and I get an error for the settings for some reason:

`django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting TEMPLATES, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.`

Here is a snippet of my transformed .JSON file:

```
[{'repo_id': 20661, 'repo_name': 'Edge', 'creation_date': '2018-09-29T21:28:51Z', 'last_updated': '2018-12-05T19:30:11Z', 'watchers': 0, 'forks_count': 0, 'issues_count': 0, 'main_language': 'CSS', 'repo_size': 4252}, ...]
```

and here is the MySQL schema:

```
mysql> describe app_repository;
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| creation_date | varchar(21)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| last_updated  | varchar(30)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| main_language | varchar(30)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| qty_forks     | int(10) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| qty_issues    | int(10) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| qty_watchers  | int(10) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| repo_id       | int(10) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| repo_name     | varchar(50)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| repo_size     | int(10) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I can enter the `shell` and manually enter data like in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields) but that is not a scalable solution to the problem.

I'm expecting to be able automatically sync the `.JSON` files to their respective table.

All of my extracted and transformed .json files are being stored in `/django_project_name/django_app_name/fixtures` and in my `settings.py` file I have the fixture file path setup:

```
# Fixtures that get loaded into the DB instance
FIXTURE_DIRS = (
    '/django_project_name/django_app_name/fixtures',
)
```

my templates are structured like so:

```
├── django_project_name
│   ├── django_app_name
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   │   ├── admin.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   │   ├── models.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   │   ├── urls.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   │   └── views.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   ├── apps.py
│   │   ├── migrations
│   │   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   │   ├── 0002_auto_20190506_1238.py
│   │   │   ├── 0003_auto_20190506_1629.py
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   └── __pycache__
│   │   │       ├── 0001_initial.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   │       ├── 0002_auto_20190506_1238.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   │       ├── 0003_auto_20190506_1629.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   │       └── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── templates
│   │   │   └── app
│   │   │       ├── discussions.html
│   │   │       ├── repositories.html
│   │   │       ├── repository.html
│   │   │       ├── team_members.html
│   │   │       └── teams.html
│   │   ├── tests.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── views.py
│   ├── db.sqlite3
│   ├── fixtures
│   │   ├── initial_data.json
│   │   ├── repos_extraction_2019-05-06-13-23-59.json
│   │   ├── repos_transformed_2019-05-06-13-23-59.json
│   │   ├── teams_extraction_2019-05-06-15-49-47.json
│   │   └── teams_transformed_2019-05-06-15-49-47.json
│   ├── iHand
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   │   ├── settings.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   │   ├── urls.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   │   └── wsgi.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── settings.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── wsgi.py
│   └── manage.py
```

I would appreciate any and all help in getting a solution to loading this data! Thank you so much for your time and help! Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For using `loaddata` on json data, the stracture of the file must be:

```
{ "model": "", "pk": ID, "fields": OriginalJsonData }
```

You can run this short script to transform to the correct json structure before loading the data

```
import json

file_name='YOUR_JSON_DATA_FILE'
pk = 0
new_list = []

with open('{}.json'.format(file_name)) as json_data:
    d = json.load(json_data)    
    for item in d:
        pk+=1
        item = {"model": "modelname.modelname", "pk": pk, "fields": item}
        new_list.append(item)
        json_data.close()


def list_to_json_file(list_of_dicts, file_name):
    with open(file_name+'.json', 'w') as file:
        json.dump(list_of_dicts, file)
    print('{}.Json file created'.format(file_name))


list_to_json_file(new_list, 'JSON_for_django')
```

and then use `loaddata` on the new json file.

Don't forget `makemigrations` and `migrate` again after this process.